# Executing jquery in HTML5 web component import

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-component

I am attempting to load a web component using the HTML5 import tag. Here, the index file loads and places the loaded component (language.html) where I want it. This language.html file contains a button and a selector, and the expected behavior is to toggle the visibility of the selector when the button is clicked.

The loading works well in all the browsers I am testing on, *visually*. It is *also* executing the component's JavaScript, which leverages jquery. But it is not adding the click behavior to the button, as expected.

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link href="language.html" rel="import" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('HTMLImportsLoaded', function () {
            var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
            var content = link.import.querySelector('#language');
            document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(content, true));
            $(document).ready(function() {
                languageReady();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's language.html

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="language">
    <input id="language_button" type="button" value="click me" />
    <div id="language_selector">
        <select>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function languageReady() {
        console.log("language ready");
        console.log($("#language_button")[0].type);
        $("#language_button").click(function () {
            $("#language_selector").toggle();
        });
    }
</script>
```

In the console, I see the logged statements each time in all browsers, and no errors are being thrown that I can see. When I place everything in the same file (i.e., not using an import), everything works as expected. From the second log statement, it is clear that the button has already been loaded.

What am I doing wrong that is preventing the click behavior from executing as expected?

Comment: Using the debugger or console.log statements you should be able to pretty easily figure out where exactly this isn't working;. Either it's unable to find the button, is finding the wrong button, or if the handler isn't able to find the div.  Dig in and figure out where it fails.

Comment: In my description above, I have identified some of this. For example, from the second console.log statement, it clear that it is finding the button, and it is finding the right button. I just added another log, and it demonstrated it is also finding the div.

Comment: How do you know it's the right button? did you select all buttons with said id attribute (attribute equals selector) to ensure there's only one?

Comment: Did you inspect the div to see if the style attribute is being added/removed?

Comment: In the less sanitized version of this question, I have alt-text and had it print the .alt.

Comment: Right, but did you confirm that there isn't a copy of it elsewhere in the html? seems like you're just assuming.

Comment: I did inspect the html, and the div isn't being modified in any way. The HTML looks exactly as expected, with only one copy of the loaded content in it.

Comment: basically, the code you have is fine, proven by the fact that it works standalone. therefore, the problem *must* be related to the thing you added that made it not work, webcomponents. my guess is it's creating a copy of the language.html elsewhere on the page that is causing your jquery to target the incorrect elements.

Comment: That's a good guess. Unfortunately, the DOM explorer doesn't bear that out.

Comment: Not even the event handlers section on the right? If the code you are running is running, and it's finding a button, if it's the right button you'll see an event handler.

Comment: No; there's nothing registered there, except for 2 from webcomponents.js.

Comment: `console.log($("[id=language_button]").length)` before your binding

Comment: Thanks for this, Kevin. It turned out that it is expressing twice (once in the header where the link is, and thus not displaying visually) and once in the actual HTML. Jquery is likely (and correctly) assuming the ID is unique and placing grabbing the first one it finds from top to bottom. Just dropping the link line where I want it seemed to do the trick. From here, the path is clear, but I wanted to write this up for posterity, and to thank you.

Comment: yeah, jquery uses document.getElementById when you select just an id, and that of course grabs the only valid element with said id, the first one. That kinda makes you question why it's being duplicated in the header... that seems flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is way simpler then your making it.

You  are missing the on click handler on the button
onclick="languageReady()"
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_html